# Regular expression: prevent entering numbers starting with 550, if length is 8, or starting with 393 if length is 5

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to understand regex, and I want to prevent entering numbers starting with 550, if length is 8, or starting with 393 if length is 5.

Tried it here (https://regex101.com/) and the correct expression is shown below

```
^((?!550)\d{8}|(?!393)\d{5})$
```

but the mask in my code works in «online» mode, and for some reason allows only numbers starting with 550 or 393, the rest of the input is forbidden (can't even enter 10000). How to remake this expression?

Comment: If you have a problem with the code, please post the code. A mere regex won't help us understand what the issue is.

Comment: Would you mind accepting one of the answers if it helped you or point out which issues you faced with the proposed solutions?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest not to tackle this problem with regular expressions. There is no easy way to express "any string except for this particular string".

**My implementation:**

```
let accept = function (v) {
  v = v.toString();
  if (v.substr(0, 3) === '550')
    return v.length !== 8;
  else if (v.substr(0, 3) === '393')
    return v.length !== 5;
  return true;
}
```

**Testcases:**

```
>> accept(12)
true
>> accept(12345678)
true
>> accept(55045678)
false
>> accept(55145678)
true
>> accept(39345)
false
>> accept(39445)
true
>> # special case
>> accept(550 * 10e155)
true
>> (550 * 10e155).toString()  # reason
"5.5e+158"
```

This implementation will also work for very large numbers, just because very large integers are represented in exponential representation.

If you are still sure, you want to use regular expressions, here you go:

```
let accept = (v) => ((/^((?!550)\d{8}|(?!393)\d{5}|\d{0,4}|\d{6,7}|\d{9,})$/).exec(v) !== null)
```

You need to define alternation paths for the regular expression which will accept the string if it has length not equal to 5 and 8.

```
>> accept(12)
true
>> accept(12345678)
true
>> accept(55045678)
false
>> accept(55145678)
true
>> accept(39345)
false
>> accept(39445)
true
>> accept(550 * 10e155)
false
```

This implementation fails, because you need to properly implement the floating point representation of numbers in Javascript in order to accept large numbers. This is tedious. I don't recommend this approach.

Answer (score 0):

I think your regex is wrong. It does not even allow matching numbers with length different to 5 or 8.

You may want to try this: `^(?:(?!550)\d{8}|(?!393)\d{5}|(?!\d{5}$|\d{8}$)\d+)$`

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/wJmhs6/1/)**

**Explained:**

```
^                              # begin of line/string
  (?:                          # group of options (separated by '|'
       (?!550)\d{8}            # 8 digits not starting by 550
     | (?!393)\d{5}            # 5 digits not starting by 393
     | (?!\d{5}$|\d{8}$) \d+   # some digits that must not be 5 and 8 and then end of line (5 and 8 should be treated above)
  )
$                              # end of line/string
```

If you also want to allow big numbers as in scientific notation, use this instead: `^(?:.*e\+.*|(?!550)\d{8}|(?!393)\d{5}|(?!\d{5}$|\d{8}$)\d+)$`

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/wJmhs6/3/)**

It basically adds `.*e\+.*` as an option (searches for `e` followed by `+`)

Comment: Fails for large numbers. `(/^(?:(?!550)\d{8}|(?!393)\d{5}|(?!\d{5}$|\d{8}$)\d+)$/).exec(550 * 10e155) === null`.

Comment: Please, could you doublecheck? It matches `1321321321321321321321321321321` without problems. See https://regex101.com/r/wJmhs6/2/

Comment: Oh... that large, with scientific notation. Well, you are right.

Comment: But you are also right in that sense that if you provide the number as a *string* (as regex101 does), it works for arbitrary long integers. So it really depends on the environment @Ican is working with. Let's keep this special case as it is. We need more information.

Comment: I'll edited my answer to include a new regex considering this special case